# Is $a^n b^m$ never regular if n and m have some relation between them?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I know what regular and context free language are and how regular language needs finite memory and other stuff.

What concerns me is that I think if $a^nb^m$ such that $n$ and $m$ have some relation between them then they can not be regular. But I can't find any such thing written anywhere. Am I correct to state so?

Comment: Hint: Is $a^nb^n$ regular or not regular? Why is that? And if $a^nb^n$ is not regular, what do you suspect $a^nb^m$ is? I am assuming that by *relation between them* you mean for example that $n$ is greater than $m$, or that $m$ is greater than or equal to $n$, and so on.

Comment: i know a^n b^n is not regular.We have to count numbers of a's and b's for that .we need stack .hence context free."relation between them you mean for example that n is greater than m, or that m is greater than or equal to n, and so on"...yes i mean that .here also n =m is a relation hence not regular. thats my point

Comment: So if you have a language that satisfies the description of you language, and it is not regular, what does that say about your language in more general terms? If $a^nb^m, n = m$, is not regular, does that say anything about your language $L$ with any kind of binary relation $R$?

Comment: it says that if a relation exists between  n and m  it can not be regular.because we have to keep track of relation and dont know if we will be able to do that in O(1) space.

Comment: You should carefully define what you mean by "have some relation between them" since $\{a^nb^m \mid n \equiv m\pmod{15}\}$ is regular, for instance.

Comment: @RickDecker  considering  ur example for  n <15 , n=m .hence a^n b^n is not regular for n<15 .

Comment: @sandeepbisht. The language $\{a^nb^n\mid n<15\}$ is finite, hence regular.

Answer (score 5):

For a relation $R(n,m)$, let $L_R = \{ a^n b^m : R(n,m) \}$. Call a relation *residual* if for some $k \geq 1$ and for some $A \subseteq [k]^2$,
$$ R(n,m) \Leftrightarrow (n,m) \pmod{k} \in A. $$
Call a relation *semi-residual* if it differs from a residual relation by a finite number of points.

**Claim:** $L_R$ is regular iff $R$ is semi-residual.

**Proof:** It is not hard to check that if $R$ is semi-residual then $L_R$ is regular. For the other direction, consider an automaton for $L_R$. For each state $\sigma$, let $L_\sigma$ be the set of all $n$ such that upon reading $a^n$, the automaton reaches $\sigma$. Since $L_\sigma$ is unary, it is eventually periodic. By taking the least common multiple of all periods, we see that the state that for $n \geq n_0$, the automaton find itself upon reading $a^n$ depends only on $n\pmod{k_a}$ from some $k_a$. Doing the same for $b^m$, we see that for $n \in L_\sigma$, the set of all $m$ such that $a^n b^m \in L$ is eventually periodic, and so for $m \geq m_0$, depends only on $\sigma$ and on $m\pmod{k_b}$ for some $k_b$. Taking $k$ to be the LCM of $k_a,k_b$, we find that for $n \geq n_0, m \geq m_0$, $a^n b^m \in L$ depends only on $(n,m) \pmod{k}$. Hence the corresponding $R$ is semi-residual.

Comment: can we say LR is not regular if R is not semi-residual ?

Comment: @sandeepbisht If you believe my claim, then it implies that $L_R$ is not regular if $R$ is not semi-residual. Perhaps you want to look up the meaning of *iff* (if and only if).

Comment: "Call a relation residual if for some k≥1 and for some A⊆[k]2". why [k]^2  why not 2^k ?

Answer (score 4):

Let $L = \{ a, b \in \Sigma \mid a^nb^m, R(n,m) \}$. This language *may* be regular: if for example $R = \mathbb{N} \times  \mathbb{N}$, then $L = a^*b^*$. So you can't say whether $L$ is regular or not without knowing something about $R$.

There *are* languages with a relation $R$ that are not regular; for example $L = a^nb^n$.

Comment: It should be possible to get an intuition about allowable $R$ from [Myhill-Nerode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem).

Comment: Another example when $L$ is regular is when $R(n,m)$ states that $n,m$ have the same parity. Using Myhill–Nerode, one should be able to come up with a complete list of all $R(n,m)$ for which $L$ is regular.

Comment: @Raphael Intuition, possibly. Are you aware of anything we can say formally about the connection between properties of $R$ and the regularity of $L$?

Comment: @C.Brand I would guess that $R$ has to have finitely many "equivalence" classes. I'm not sure whether that's sufficient.